# How to plot vector (not rastered as pixels) graphics in opencv

Tags: matlab, opencv

Being used to Matlab and its great capabilities of drawing vector graphics, I am looking for something similar in OpenCV. OpenCV [drawing functions](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html) seem to raster the lines or points at pixel level. Currently, I am dumping the data into text, copy-paste to Matlab and doing all the plots. I also thought about using [Matlab engine](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/introducing-matlab-engine.html) to pass it the parameters and running plots, but it seems to be too much mess for simple debug operation.

I want to be able to do the following:

- Zoom in, out of the image
- Draw a line/point which is re-rastered each time I do zoom, like in Matlab.

Currently, I found [image watch plugin](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e682d542-7ef3-402c-b857-bbfba714f78d) to take care of zooming, but it does not help with the second part.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenCV has a lot of capabilities to process an image but only minimal ones for displaying the result. It has nothing that can display vector graphics like Matlab. When I need to see polygons on image (or just polygons) I am dumping them to file and using third party viewer (usually [Giv viewer](http://giv.sourceforge.net/giv/)).